# Populate select element options in form with json data without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, forms

Context: In my form, I set it up so that users can insert records to the db if the option they need isn't already available in the select element of my form. They simply add the new data via a popup modal window which is processed and then inserts the new data in my database and is immediately available via json. No problems there.

Problem: The new data that is being added to the db is immediately available via json, but the select elements will not update without a full page refresh. How can I make it so that my script will parse the json for all data without having to refresh the page? I know this is possible, perhaps the method I'm using in my script is wrong?

Select elements from form:

```
<select name="inputSupplier" id="inputSupplier" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Select supplier...</option>
</select>

<select name="inputManufacturer" id="inputManufacturer" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Select manufacturer...</option>
</select>

<select name="inputStatus" id="inputStatus" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Select asset status...</option>
</select>

<select name="inputCategory" id="inputCategory" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Select category...</option>
</select>
```

Here is a sample of the json data that is created from a database query:

```
{
"suppliers":
    {"1":"Amazon"},
"manufacturers":
    {"1":"Apple","5":"Lenovo"},
"categories":
    {"2":"Tablet"},
"status":
    {"1":"Ready to Deploy","2":"Deployed","3":"Damaged"}
}
```

Here is my current working code to pull and parse the json:

```js
$(document).ready(function () 
{
 $.ajax({
  url : '/json/collection.json',
  type : 'GET',
  dataType : 'json',
  success:function(data)
  {
   $.each(data.suppliers, function(key,value){
    $('select[name="inputSupplier"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
   });
   $.each(data.manufacturers, function(key,value){
    $('select[name="inputManufacturer"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
   });
   $.each(data.status, function(key,value){
    $('select[name="inputStatus"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
   });
   $.each(data.categories, function(key,value){
    $('select[name="inputCategory"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
   });
  }
 });
});
```

Revised code:

Added on click event to select elements in the form that call the function below it.

```
onclick="refreshData()"
```

```
function refreshData() { 

    var suppliers = 'select[name="inputSupplier"]';
    var manufacturers = 'select[name="inputManufacturer"]';
    var status = 'select[name="inputStatus"]';
    var categories = 'select[name="inputCategory"]';

    $(suppliers).empty().html('<option value="0">Select supplier...</option>');
    $(manufacturers).empty().html('<option value="0">Select manufacturer...</option>');
    $(status).empty().html('<option value="0">Select status...</option>');
    $(categories).empty().html('<option value="0">Select category...</option>');

    $.ajax({
        url : '/json/collection.json',
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        success:function(data)
        {
            $.each(data.suppliers, function(key,value){
                $('select[name="inputSupplier"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
            });
            $.each(data.manufacturers, function(key,value){
                $('select[name="inputManufacturer"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
            });
            $.each(data.status, function(key,value){
                $('select[name="inputStatus"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
            });
            $.each(data.categories, function(key,value){
                $('select[name="inputCategory"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
            });
        }
}); }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code, as long as the HTML & JSON are as you've provided them. See https://jsfiddle.net/ukmvhzt9/. I'd look at the Network tab of Developer Tools to see if there's anything wrong with the AJAX call.

Comment: I looked at the jsfiddle you created and it's doing the same thing as my script. For instance, If you add a new supplier to the data, the select element does not update with the new item.

Comment: Well, obviously not. You'd have to call the `success` function with the updated data. Likewise, in your question, you'd need to call ajax again. It's not magic, you have to tell it to go get new data. Also, you'll probably want to remove the options you added previously, unless the server only returns new items to add...

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with using ajax. I was under the impression that it would update itself with any new data added to the json. Obviously, I'm incorrect. Can you be a little more specific? How do I trigger it to go get that new data?

Comment: I would write a function, something like `function refreshData() { $.ajax(...); }`. Then, you'll need to decide how often users need to see new data. Say it's once every minute. Add a call like [`setInterval(refreshData, 60000)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) (60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds). If you want the server to do it, it would depend on what server technology you're using. You'll probably want to keep the selected index in memory so that you can reset it after the reload.

Comment: See revised code above. I added an onclick event to each select so that way the refreshData function would run each time a relevant select was clicked, all select elements would refresh. Can you look at what I've written and see if that's the most efficient way? @msg that's a good idea as well. I'll implement that once I'm sure the function I'm using now is the most optimal. Thoughts?

Comment: Through testing, the revised function works, but when I select one of the values in the select element, it's not retaining the selection. Not sure what to do here.

Comment: You may refer the below web page:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/18556/Using-a-drop-down-box-to-populate-a-second-drop-down-box.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the json only on `document.ready`, you should do it after submitting the modal too. This is what I came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Initial load
  refreshData();

  // Also refresh data when modal is submitted. 
  // Adjust selector to match your modal or add the call to your current submit function.
  // Since ajax is async, you could get stale data if this call ends before the submission
  // Put the refreshData inside the success handler of the submit function
  $('#modal form').submit(function() {
    // Post form, etc
    refreshData();
  });
});

function refreshData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/json/collection.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      refreshSelect('inputSupplier', data.suppliers);
      refreshSelect('inputManufacturer', data.manufacturers);
      refreshSelect('inputStatus', data.status);
      refreshSelect('inputCategory', data.categories);
    }
  });
}

function refreshSelect(name, data) {
  // Select by id
  let $elem = $('#' + name);
  // Get current value
  let oldValue = $elem.val();
  // Get "template" value with value 0, which is the first element
  let emptyOption = $elem.children('option').first();
  // Empty the element and add the option. We are back to initial state
  $elem.html(emptyOption);
  // Append elements retrieved from backend
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $elem.append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
  });
  // Restore selection
  $elem.val(oldValue);
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Works perfectly. Just have to add a call to refreshData on the form in my modal window, but that's an easy edit.